# Creating a box surrounded by text in Tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, box, adjustbox

How is it possible for me to put a box of adjustable size surrounded by a text in a latex document ?

For instance : my inspiration is from the yellow boxes in this image :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, adjustbox}
    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
Paragraphe de test pour essayer de placer une boîte 

\tcbset{colback=green!5!white,colframe=green!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries, width = 5cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = Third box]
Description
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: `\input{insbox}`, or `\usepackage{wrapfigure}`, or...

Comment: The book has a wonderful and amazing style. How can I view more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap text around a `tcolorbox` you can simply put it inside a `wrapfigure`, using the `wrapfig` package. To make the tcolorbox smaller than the textwidth, simply use the option `width=`.
Here is an example with a box similar to the yellow in the provided picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% new packages:
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{BgYellow}{HTML}{FFF59C}
\definecolor{FrameYellow}{HTML}{F7A600}

\newtcolorbox{mybox2}[1][]{enhanced,
before skip=2mm,after skip=2mm,
width=0.5\textwidth,
halign=center,
colback=BgYellow,colframe=FrameYellow,boxrule=0.2mm,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0cm,yshift*=0mm-\tcboxedtitleheight},
varwidth boxed title*=-3cm,
boxed title style={frame code={
\path[left color=FrameYellow,right color=FrameYellow,
middle color=FrameYellow]
([xshift=-0mm]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=0mm]frame.north east)
[rounded corners=0mm]-- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north east)
-- (frame.south east) -- (frame.south west)
-- ([xshift=0mm,yshift=0mm]frame.north west)
[sharp corners]-- cycle;
},interior engine=empty,
},
  sharp corners,rounded corners=southeast,arc is angular,arc=3mm,
  underlay={%
    \path[fill=BgYellow!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    \path[draw=FrameYellow,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm,color=FrameYellow] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    },
  drop fuzzy shadow,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title={#1}}

\begin{document}
Paragraphe de test pour essayer de placer une boîte 


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{mybox2}[Third box]
Description
\end{mybox2}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

This produces the output:
[image]

You can change the box to the left side using `{L}` instead of `{R}` in `\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.6\textwidth}`(**NB** make sure the wrapfig is wider than the box!). You can also change the width of the box in the third line in the code (`width=0.5\textwidth`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Could you tell me please what is the `enhanced` environment that you use in the first line of the code ?

Comment: From the package documentation: "[Enhanced] translates the drawing commands of the core package into tikz path commands. Therefore, it allows all tikz high level options for these paths and has
more flexibility compared to the standard skin. You pay for this with some
prolonged compilation time" (Enhanced is a "skin" that provides "enhanced" features to the box).

Comment: Is there a way to write the text inside the `mybox2` such as it should be justified on the right margin like a standard text ? For instance, if I try to write `\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{mybox2}[Mémo]
\lipsum[1-1]
\end{mybox2}
\end{wrapfigure}` the text appears to be "centered". Thank you

Comment: Just take away the `halign=center` in the 4th line (under `width`).

Comment: Also, you can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644989/how-do-i-write-a-note-in-a-framed-box/645051#645051